# How to generate random date in Go lang?

Tags: date, go, time

```
time.Date(2009, 11, 17, 20, 34, 58, 651387237, time.UTC)
```

The above code gives us a timestamp but, what if I want to fetch only the date part and the time part separately? Is it possible to use split()?

Comment: What does _" filter this time from this timestamp"_ mean? You want to get back the number `651387237` from the `time.Time` value? And what random date? In what range?

Comment: @icza I want to get a random date say May 22, 2009. How do I get that?

Comment: What is the _range_ you want random dates in? Min and Max dates?

Answer (score 30):

You can use `math/rand` to generate a random date like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func randate() time.Time {
    min := time.Date(1970, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
    max := time.Date(2070, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
    delta := max - min

    sec := rand.Int63n(delta) + min
    return time.Unix(sec, 0)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/x1CK6nIO-v

Comment: This is an acceptable way to generate a random date and shouldn't be marked down.

Comment: It works, but it isn't evenly distributed. Eg. March 1 will appear much more often than it should. Even if you do the obvious fix of limiting the day of month to valid numbers, you then just change the bad distribution and dates in Feb. will be chosen more than they should.

Comment: Good point @JamesAntill I've updated my answer, but to my defense, it was not my intention to provide a full-fledged solution without knowing more about the problem, all I intended to do is to point out that `math/rand` could be used for something like random dates, whether that's something the OP is looking for, I cannot tell.

Comment: Can you explain this more? I would argue it's a code only answer and therefore poor quality.